# Rails - Find by username and post id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my posts controller, right now I'm finding posts by user_id and post_id and it works perfectly fine

```
    def find_post
        @track = Track.find_by(user_id: params[:id], post_id: params[:post_id])
    end
```

I am looking for a way to find the post instead of the user_id, by  the username
for example if it's finding the post like this:

```
/:user_id/:post_id
```

To something like:

```
/:username/:post_id
```

So how can I access the username parameter in the url? or is there a better process for this?

Comment: you can create a function called find_post_by_user and in the route create the other endpoint `/:username/:post_id` and then reference that route to the new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails's Router maps the `:placeholder`s to `params` object-keys. Like

```
/:user_id/:slug
```

maps `user_id` to `params[:user_id]`

```
/:username/:slug
```

maps `username` to `params[:username]`. So you can access the supplied username via `params` object. and make DB calls like

```
user  = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
@post = user.posts.find(params[:post_id])
```

You cannot find post directly from `username` because you have no information that which username does this post belongs to. You only have `user_id` as `foreign_key` but not `username`.

Comment: Got it working after changing to `user.posts.find_by_slug`